# aspxauth cookie getting stripped in iframe

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iframe, asp.net-membership

We have an asp.net MVC website (4.5.2), using the asp.net membership provider that displays  health and wellness videos. One feature we have provided to our clients is an iframe version of our videos. We generate links that auto-authenticate (bypassing the authentication) allowing users to embed the video on their site.

However, this suddenly stopped working on all browsers on Jan 21, 2020.  When we looked closer, we noticed that all cookies in the child frame were appearing, except the .ASPXAUTH cookie, which seems to have disappeared.   The following link illustratest this -- while the direct link to the resource appears correctly., for some reason, when embedded in an iframe, the authentication fails and the video does not appear.

Even if we have  the cookie on our browser, from logging in on a separate tab, we are getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, auth cookies on iframes stopped working on v4.5.1. Upgrading to framwework v4.7.2 fixed the issue. I think it might be related to the samesite cookie issue referenced in this block: https://brockallen.com/2019/01/11/same-site-cookies-asp-net-core-and-external-authentication-providers/ although, interestingly, we experienced exceptions in all browsers (Edge,IE11, Firefox etc) and not just Chrome